# SUM 2 columns Row * Row

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, matrix-multiplication

I have 2 columns that, starting from row 3, have values I need to sum row * row.

What I mean is something like:

```
SUM(M3*I3, M4*I4, M5*I5, ecc..)
```

I found `ArrayFormula`, but I am not sure its what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(M3:M*I3:I))
```

Answer (score 1):

There's the function [SUMPRODUCT()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094294?hl=en) specifically designed for this:

```
=SumProduct(M3:M,I3:I)
```

Comment: it does not work :(

Comment: that is not helpful. I tested it just to make sure and it's working fine.

Comment: googlesheet is not helpful. It just says "Error of the formula"

Comment: this is actually helpful. It means that your locale is set to a country that uses comma as decimal separator, hence you should use semi colon to separate the arguments. `=SumProduct(M3:M;I3:I)`